# Best way to query database though browser once i have a java webserver

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, ajax, webserver

I have a java webserver running local, and i want to make database queries in realtime using AJAX. How can i do that ? I want the simplest way, like:

**$bt.click -> $ajax request -> query database -> return boolean -> if data.success: do something**

I'm finding many options, all very different from one another, and no one does what i need.

Thank you.

Comment: why am i getting downvoted ? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that is the most used today, is to make WebService in JSon or XML, ans request the server via ajax on these Web Services.

Comment: yea, i know.. i mean, do you have any simple example of how can i implement it ?

Comment: see here, all it explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599968/calling-rest-webservice-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: thanks man ! i did it, works well.. now i'm trying to send data through ajax data parameter, instead of using url params.. i dont know how, yet, but i'm getting closer :D